# Wordpress.org website not importing correctly into wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress

I have no idea how in the world am I not able to find a tutorial on this so I'm asking this question here.Here are the steps I've done:
1.Download wordpress from wordpress.org;
2.Extract the folder into Xampp/htdocs;
3.Rename the folder to 'designers';
4.Open localhost/designers in the browser and initialise the website (created a db in phpmyadmin also named designers,set the user as root,created the password,imported a modded version of elementor PRO necessary to edit the website);
5.Created a new page and proceeded to edit it with elementor (gave a name to the page,skipped all the other steps and proceeded with 'Edit blank template');
6.After finishing the job with elementor,I deleted all the other pages and posts and set the new created page as default home page (when you click the visit button on the wp dashboard it takes you directly to the elementor created page);
7.Exported the website by selecting All content and then imported the .xml import file into wordpress.com by selecting Import from file.
The steps above are what I've done from setting up the website all the way to importing it into wordpress.com but the website doesn't look at all like what it supposed to look like.
Here are some screenshots of the difference between the 2 versions:https://imgur.com/ektray8
I did everything according to the wordpress blog.Am I doing something wrong?Did I skip something?

Comment: WordPress.com is far more limited in its support of plugins than .org. [Please note that if you use WordPress.com you will need the Business Plan to support Elementor.](https://elementor.com/help/can-i-use-elementor-pro-on-wordpress-com/)